# Ubuntu 22.04 Server losing dns at random

Tags: server, 22.04, netplan

It happens at random, could be a day could be 2 weeks. Boot up the server everything is fine.

After a random time I'm unable to resolve any web addresses. Checking the server I get the following.

```
resolvectl status | grep Current
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
```

For some reason my DNS server has disappeared. I can fix the problem by simply running

sudo netplan apply
Then when I check

```
resolvectl status | grep Current
Current Scopes: DNS
Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.254
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
Current Scopes: none
```

Any idea's why this is happening and how I can fix it?